# Rendering multiple .rdlc reports into a single PDF using PDFSharp

Tags: c#, pdf, rendering, rdlc, pdfsharp

I am running multiple reports and combining them into a single PDF file.  For each report, I pass the datasource, parameters, and report path to the following.  The result is a PDF file with the correct number of pages, but all pages are blank.  What am I missing?

```
LocalReport report = null;
PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument();

private void ProcessReport(
    ReportDataSource reportDS, 
    ReportParameter[] reportParms, 
    string reportPath)
{
    string format = "PDF";
    string deviceInfo = null;
    string encoding = String.Empty;
    string mimeType = String.Empty;
    string extension = String.Empty;
    Warning[] warnings = null;
    string[] streamIDs = null;

    report = new LocalReport();
    report.EnableExternalImages = true;
    report.ReportPath = reportPath;

    if (reportParms != null)
        report.SetParameters(reportParms);

    if (reportDS != null)
        report.DataSources.Add(reportDS);

    Byte[] pdfArray = report.Render(
        format, 
        deviceInfo, 
        out mimeType, 
        out encoding,
        out extension, 
        out streamIDs, 
        out warnings);

    //Stream s = new MemoryStream(pdfArray);
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(pdfArray);

    PdfDocument tempPDFDoc = PdfReader.Open(ms, PdfDocumentOpenMode.Import);

    for (int i = 0; i < tempPDFDoc.PageCount; i++)
    {
        PdfPage page = tempPDFDoc.Pages[i];
        pdfDoc.AddPage(page);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try generating the reports with a different setting as described in this thread:
http://forum.pdfsharp.net/viewtopic.php?p=1613#p1613

If you provide us with some files that do not work, we can try to fix this in PDFsharp.

Comment: Not sure where to put `"<DeviceInfo><HumanReadablePDF>True</HumanReadablePDF></DeviceInfo>"` (As mentioned in the link given) this code , can anyone share the code where these changes take place ? Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You need to change your string deviceInfo = null;
to `deviceInfo="<DeviceInfo><HumanReadablePDF>True</HumanReadablePDF></DeviceInfo>";`